# Counterexample about weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be Banach space. Let $S_n, S, T_n, T \in \mathcal{B}(X,X).$ Show that $S_n \to S $(strongly) and $T_n \to T$ (weakly) doesn't necessarily imply that $S_nT_n \to ST$ (weakly).

I can't find the counterexample, can anyone help me find it?

Comment: What are the $S$'s and $T$'s?

Comment: In the edited version of the question, are you sure that you want the data to be elements of the dual of $X$ (usually what $X'$ is written to mean, i.e. $\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{C})$ (or $\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{R})$), instead of perhaps elements of $\mathcal{B}(X,X)$ (often written $\mathcal{B}(X)$)?  Just curious about what the setting of the question is. Operator composition is a more commonly analyzed thing than the pointwise product of linear functionals.

Comment: You are right, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint / counter-example:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space with ONB $\{e_n\}_{n\geq1}$. For any $n\geq1$, set $$T_nx=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\langle x,e_k\rangle e_{k-n},\;\;\;\;x\in\mathcal{H}$$

1. Show that $(T_n)\subset\mathcal{B(H)}$.
2. Show that $T_n\to0$ strongly, so $T_n\to0$ weakly, too. Since involution is WOT-WOT continuous, we also have that $T_n^*\to0$ weakly.
3. Show that $T_nT_n^*\require{cancel}\cancel{\longrightarrow}0$ weakly by observing that $T_nT_n^*e_1=e_1$ for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Comment: @KahyUs Glad I could help

Comment: What does mean WOT-WOT? please.

Comment: @Piquito WOT= weak operator topology, i am saying that the involution is a continuous map when we regard both the domain and target space $\mathcal{B(H)}$ with the weak topology

Comment: @JustDroppedIn.-

Comment: @JustDroppedIn.- Thanks you very much!